# Including images and animations in same environment

Tags: beamer, graphics, environments, overlays, animate

In my beamer presentation, I have three images and a merged pdf that I want to animate using the `animate` package. The set up is as follows: the three images are lined up next to each other, and I want to replace the third image with the animation. That is, on the first slide, I want the three images to be next to each other, and on the second slide, I want the left two images to be next to the animation (so the animation is replacing the third image).

Here is a picture:

[image]

Here is a MWE to show what I tried to do:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{black} $\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$} %style of item
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.75em}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics<1->[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_lasso.pdf}
    \includegraphics<1->[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_ridge.pdf}
    \includegraphics<1>[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_enet.pdf}
    \animategraphics<2>[autoplay, loop, width = 0.33\textwidth]{30}{enet_ani_merged}{}{}
\end{figure}

The \textit{shape} of the penalty can give some idea of the type of shrinkage imposed on the model.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Sharp corners $\to$ sparsity! \Laughey[1.5][yellow][pink]
    \item Round corners $\to$ only shrinkage!
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The file names of the three images are `cont_lasso.pdf`, `cont_ridge.pdf`, and `cont_enet.pdf`, and the name of the merged pdf for the animation is `enet_ani_merged.pdf`.

**EDIT**

For clarification, I want to make it such that the animation automatically starts playing when I begin the second slide.

After some experimentation, it seems my issue is because putting the `animategraphics` command inside a `figure` environment is not allowed, and not because of the overlays. So I now want to know, how am I able to put the two graphics and the animation in the same environment?

Comment: It is possible with the `ocgx2` package to make the third image a link that when clicked activates the animation.

Comment: @AndréC I will look into that, but I should have mentioned that I want the animation to start playing as soon as I press the clicker to start the next slide. I will update the question with this info.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `figure` environment as well as the overlay specifications from the `\includegraphics` commands?

Comment: @leandriis that works for me! Even though I don't need it here, just out of curiosity, do you know if there is a way you can add a caption to this? I put them in a `center` environment.

Comment: Maybe `\captionof` from the `caption` package.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of `leandriis` comment, here is the code for anyone who would like to see what the final output looks like. I had to add `noframenumbering` so the frame number does not change.

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{Luebeck}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\color{black} $\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$} %style of item
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.75em}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contour plots}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_lasso.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_ridge.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_enet.pdf}
    %\animategraphics[autoplay, loop, width = 0.33\textwidth]{30}{enet_ani_merged}{}{}
\end{figure}

The \textit{shape} of the penalty can give some idea of the type of shrinkage imposed on the model.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Sharp corners $\to$ sparsity! \Laughey[1.5][yellow][pink]
    \item Round corners $\to$ only shrinkage!
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Contour plots}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_lasso.pdf}
    \includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_ridge.pdf}
    %\includegraphics[width = 0.33\textwidth]{cont_enet.pdf}
    \animategraphics[autoplay, loop, width = 0.33\textwidth]{30}{enet_ani_merged}{}{}
\end{figure}

The \textit{shape} of the penalty can give some idea of the type of shrinkage imposed on the model.
\begin{itemize}
    \item Sharp corners $\to$ sparsity! \Laughey[1.5][yellow][pink]
    \item Round corners $\to$ only shrinkage!
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of the output (I could not find a way to screen record the pdf, the right figure is meant to be moving):

[image]